# Text color with geom_label_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

Not specific to any particular piece of code, is there a relatively straightforward way to change the color of the text in a geom_label_repel box?

Specifically, I have code that produces the below chart

[image]

The percentage in the label box is the percent change in 7-day moving average for the most recent week over the week prior.  I'd simply like to color the text red when the value is positive and green when it is negative.

The dataframe for this chart can be copied from [here](https://pastebin.com/Vn2abQ4a).

The plot code is

```
#endpoint layer
BaseEndpoints <- smDailyBaseData %>% filter(Base %in% AFMCbases) %>%
  group_by(Base) %>%
  filter(DaysSince == max(DaysSince)) %>%
  select(Base, abbv, DaysSince, newRate,label) %>%
  ungroup()

ZoomEndpoints <- BaseEndpoints %>% filter(Base != 'Edwards') %>%
  mutate(zoom = TRUE)
CAEndPoint <- BaseEndpoints %>% filter(Base == 'Edwards') %>%
  mutate(zoom = FALSE)

ZoomEndpoints <- rbind(ZoomEndpoints, CAEndPoint)

BasePlot <- smDailyBaseData %>% filter(Base %in% AFMCbases) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(DaysSince), y = newRate)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=abbv),show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_ucscgb() +
 geom_point(data = BaseEndpoints,size = 1.5,shape = 21, 
            aes(color = abbv,fill = abbv), show.legend = FALSE) +
 geom_label_repel(data=ZoomEndpoints, aes(label=label), show.legend = FALSE,
                   vjust = 0, xlim=c(105,200), size=3, direction='y') +
  labs(x = "Days Since First Confirmed Case", 
       y = "% Local Population Infected Daily") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1), face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.7)),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = rel(1))) +
  facet_zoom(xlim = c(50,120), ylim=c(0,0.011),zoom.data=zoom)



print(BasePlot)
```

Comment: Hi jerH, this should be possible, but it will be much easier to help if you provide working code with some sample data.

Comment: OK...was hoping it was a simple conceptual answer.  I will amend the OP.  My script downloads a bunch of data and does a bunch of manipulation first, which is all extraneous to this question.  I'll have to link to a dput() output on pastebin as it's too large to include in a post.

Comment: Code in the OP now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a bit of a hacky solution since you can't have two `scale_color_*`'s at the same time:

The approach centers on manually assigning the color outside of `aes` in the `geom_label_repel` call. Adding one to the `grepl` result that searches for the minus sign in the label allows you to subset the two colors. You need two colors for each label, I assume for the box and for the text, so I used `rep`.

```
smDailyBaseData %>% 
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(DaysSince), y = newRate)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=abbv),show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_ucscgb() +
 geom_point(data = BaseEndpoints,size = 1.5,shape = 21, 
            aes(color = abbv,fill = abbv), show.legend = FALSE) +
 geom_label_repel(data=ZoomEndpoints, aes(label=label),
     color = rep(c("green","red")[1+grepl("\\-\\d",as.factor(ZoomEndpoints$label))],times = 2),
     show.legend = FALSE, vjust = 0, xlim=c(105,200),
     size=3, direction='y') +
 labs(x = "Days Since First Confirmed Case", 
       y = "% Local Population Infected Daily") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1), face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.7)),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = rel(1))) +
 facet_zoom(xlim = c(50,120), ylim=c(0,0.011),zoom.data=zoom)
```

[image]

**Data Setup**

```
#source("https://pastebin.com/raw/Vn2abQ4a")
BaseEndpoints <- smDailyBaseData %>% 
  group_by(Base) %>%
  dplyr::filter(DaysSince == max(DaysSince)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Base, abbv, DaysSince, newRate,label) %>%
  ungroup()
ZoomEndpoints <- BaseEndpoints %>% filter(Base != 'Edwards') %>%
  mutate(zoom = TRUE)
CAEndPoint <- BaseEndpoints %>% filter(Base == 'Edwards') %>%
  mutate(zoom = FALSE)
ZoomEndpoints <- rbind(ZoomEndpoints, CAEndPoint)
```

Comment: if you look at your output chart, Arnold (at the top) is a negative value, but it is green, as is Robins, while Hanscom and Kirtland are also negative but are red

Comment: Sorry about that, I goofed on the regex because I didn't realize `W-P` also has a `-`. That should take care of it. Hey, it's Monday!

Comment: I can appreciate that!  I'm still getting mixed output though...I'll dig into the regex but if you happen across the answer :)

Comment: I'm happy to look more, Can you clarify where my plot is wrong? Note that I had to take your `filter(Base %in% AFMCbases)` lines out because I didn't have `AFMCbases`.

Comment: Ahh...forgot that part...but I had done the filter in constructing the dput() on pastebin so that should have no effect.  I still get Arnold at -6% in green while Hanscoat -24% is red, and Robins at -18% is green and Kirtland at -5% is red.  Hansom and Kirtland are the only reds I get, the rest are green.

Comment: You have the difference from `each = 2` to `times = 2`?

Comment: Didn't catch that...that did it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's as simple as this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c(-1, -1, 1, 1), y = c(-1, 1, 1, -1), value = c(-2, -1, 1, 2))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(label = value, colour = factor(sign(value)))) +
  lims(x = c(-100, 100), y = c(-100, 100))  +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "forestgreen"))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Now we have a more concrete example, I can see the problem more clearly. There are workarounds such as using `ggnewscale` or a hand-crafted solution such as Ian Campbell's thorough example. Personally, I would just note that you haven't used the fill scale yet, and this looks pretty good to my eye:

[image]

Comment: Okay, so I should definitely have included the plot code to begin with....its's in the OP now.  I'm already using a scale for color to control the color of the lines in the line plot, so trying to add scale_colour_manual replaces that.  Which of course then causes an error as there are 11 data series...

Comment: Sorry to bump this old thread. I get the same 'a' in legend as in -1 and 1 (factor sign value). Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: @DeathMetal add `key_glyph = draw_key_path` to the `geom_text` call.